# C# to replace strings of text in a docx

Tags: c#, replace, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

Using C#, is there a good way to find and replace a text string in a docx file without having word installed on that machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using [Open XML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/default.aspx). Here's an article which addresses your specific question: [Creating a Simple Search and Replace Utility for Word 2007 Open XML Format Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974107(office.12).aspx)

> To work with this file format, one option is to use the Open XML
> Format Application Programming Interface (API) in the
> DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging namespace. The classes, methods, and
> properties in this namespace are located in the
> DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll file. You can install this DLL file by
> installing the Open XML Format SDK version 1.0. The members in this
> namespace allow you to easily work with the package contents for Excel
> 2007 workbooks, PowerPoint 2007 presentations, and Word 2007
> documents.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Private Sub Search_Replace(ByVal file As String)
> Dim wdDoc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, True)
>
> ' Manage namespaces to perform Xml XPath queries.
> Dim nt As NameTable = New NameTable
> Dim nsManager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(nt)
> nsManager.AddNamespace("w", wordmlNamespace)
>
> ' Get the document part from the package.
> Dim xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument(nt)
> ' Load the XML in the part into an XmlDocument instance.
> xdoc.Load(wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream)
>
> ' Get the text nodes in the document.
> Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = Nothing
> nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//w:t", nsManager)
> Dim node As XmlNode
> Dim nodeText As String = ""
>
> ' Make the swap.
> Dim oldText As String = txtOldText.Text
> Dim newText As String = txtNewText.Text
> For Each node In nodes
>    nodeText = node.FirstChild.InnerText
>    If (InStr(nodeText, oldText) > 0) Then
>       nodeText = nodeText.Replace(oldText, newText)
>       ' Increment the occurrences counter.
>       numChanged += 1
>    End If
> Next
>
> ' Write the changes back to the document.
> xdoc.Save(wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create))
>
> ' Display the number of change occurrences.
> txtNumChanged.Text = numChanged
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Thanks that definitely got me started.  It looks like it is all based on System.IO.Packaging.   Since this is fairly simple, can it be done without the Open XML Format SDK?

Comment: Absolutely - I rarely use the SDK myself. I primarily program against PowerPoint (`PresentationML` and `DrawingML` as opposed to Word's `WordProcessingML`) using only `System.IO.Packaging` and Linq-to-XML. So I'll have to point you to a Ken Getz article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738371(office.12).aspx. Look for any more of his articles written in 2006 - they all use `System.IO.Packaging`. After that, he started writing articles with the SDK. You can also check out http://www.openxmldeveloper.org

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Also, this reference by Vikas Goyal helped me tremendously both in getting the answer I needed and in (mostly) understanding what was going on in the process: http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/42221/1954

Comment: @timothyawiseman: the devx article is a really good one. glad to hear this is working out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try [Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) in order to [find and replace text in Word document](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/find-and-replace-overview.html). This component doesn't require MS Office to be installed. The API is quite simple and easy to use and implement.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

Or you might try DocxTemplater. An open source library. Not as sophisticated as Aspose but open source.
https://github.com/Amberg/DocxTemplater