# Document validation / comparison

Tags: c#, docx

is there a way to compare two docx documents?

I have one that is generated from a template document where some sections are removed dynamically through bookmarks and block sections from the template.

I would like to compare the generated document with another docx which would be the expected result.

I vaguely heard of checksum comparison,

is there anybody that would have some pointers on the best way to compare 2 documents?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two RTF documents side-by-side in Word (VSTO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962280/comparing-two-rtf-documents-side-by-side-in-word-vsto)

Comment: docx4j contains code for xml differencing; I have used that from C# via IKVM

Comment: Is this for the purpose of unit testing say, or for displaying differences to the user?

Comment: @plutext : unit testing :) Thanks for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [XMLUnit for .NET](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to compare the main document parts (document.xml).

You could get the main document parts using the OpenXML SDK, or System.IO.Packaging.  See [C# to replace strings of text in a docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375811/c-to-replace-strings-of-text-in-a-docx) for more on the latter approach.

Answer (score 0):

> I vaguely heard of checksum
>   comparison.

Checksums work well for comparison of byte by byte exactness. If that's what you are looking for, then read the bytes of each document into a stream and use a `SHA256Managed` or `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` to generate a checksum for each file. If the two checksums are the same, then the two documents are most likely the same.

MD5 is not suitable for security purposes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 - see "Security") but it should be fine for comparison purposes where you are in control of both documents. Also keep in mind that checksums are not 100% unique, so there is always the remote possibility of collision.

> I have one that is generated from a
>   template document where some sections
>   are removed dynamically through
>   bookmarks and block sections from the
>   template.

However, if you are comparing section by section, then you may need to open the document up as more than raw bytes and deal with it in a structured fashion, e.g. section by section. You can programmatically open a .docx file using c# (using a variety of means); perhaps you can then perform a checksum against the contents of each section?

This thread talks about creating/manipulating .docx files using c#: [How can a Word document be created in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412/how-can-a-word-document-be-created-in-c). The same tools could be used to read one.